# Powershell Get-Mailbox loop

Tags: powershell, loops

I am using `Get-Mailbox` to grab user/mailbox names, then `Get-MailboxPermission` search.

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited -Filter {name -like "a*"} | Get-MailboxPermission | where { ($_.AccessRights -eq “FullAccess, ChangePermission”) | blah blah
```

I have a different line for each starting letter (`a*`, `b*`, `c*` etc).  This works fine but it seems like this could be done with some kind of loop (`foreach` or `foreach-object`) with an array reference ( `@("a","b")` - or it may need to be `@("a*","b*")` ) but I can work out the wildcard part later probably.

I don't run without a filter since there are too many mailboxes and memory usage is intense, using a letter by letter reference, the memory seems to drop back down at each letter (and running garbage collection between each letter seems to help - the output of each letter is written to a .csv).

Thought anyone - I feel I'm missing something simple since so far trying with an array is not working.  The result it usually spits back ALL mailboxes vs the curated letter ones (a,b,c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through an array to avoid the multiple lines.

```
$alphabet = [char[]]([int][char]'a'..[int][char]'z')

foreach ($letter in $alphabet) {  

    Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited -Filter "name -like '$letter*'" | Get-MailboxPermission | where { ($_.AccessRights -eq “FullAccess, ChangePermission”) | blah blah   

} # end foreach
```

[This topic](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/0b2a0a4f-df68-486b-8249-735f7c4fad4e/graceful-way-to-create-an-alphabet-array?forum=winserverpowershell) discusses graceful alphabet arrays.

Comment: Just got done testing.  Seemed to work fine (got about five results - pretty much what I expected).  Thank you so much.